# Close Simulator from Xcode: Running AppleScript on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, applescript

I have an AppleScript that I setup to close the iOS simulator after X amount of time. I know that in objective-c using the Cocoa framework for a Mac app, I would just easily do:

```
NSString *scriptSource = @"tell application \"iOS Simulator\" to quit";
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource];
NSError *error = nil;

[script executeAndReturnError:&error];
```

Obviously I can't do this in iOS. Is there anything that will run my AppleScript in iOS? Or does anyone know of any workarounds or ways to do this?

Or, is there a way to close the iOS Simulator from within the app using natively Objective-C, another scripting language, or add it to the build phase?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can't run AppleScript on an iOS device.

And there is no way to quit the iOS simulator from an iOS app.

Sorry.

Comment: Do you know of another way? Like can I but applescript in a build phase or achieve this through another scripting language?

Comment: Maybe if you describe what you are trying to do exactly, I might have other ideas?  


If you're *really desperate* you could do something like have your iOS app create a text file in Dropbox & then on your Mac make an AppleScript that watches for files added to dropbox & when that file shows up, the AppleScript could tell the Simulator to quit.